# Seleccionar y Guardar un ID desde una tabla relacionada en una modal a la tabla principal creando un nuevo registro- Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, modal, laravel-blade, laravel-8

es mi primera pregunta pido excusas si no soy muy claro o si es extensa la misma, entro en contexto:
Me encuentro realizando un proyecto, un horario universitario, en este caso quiero crear un nuevo grupo este incluye:

[image: Acá muestro la relación de grupos como tabla principal y horarios como segunda tabla]

todo me funciona, pero el detalle está en que no es practico para el usuario refiriéndome a la interfaz como muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Logré mostrar el código del horario pero no es nada practico]

Se muestra el campo código_horarios pero claramente no es funcional, esto me llevo a pensar en que la solución seria una modal con los datos de la tabla horarios donde el usuario pueda ver y elegir el que desee de esta manera:

[image: modal]

**Mi problema está en que no sé como seleccionar la fila, llevarme el id de ese dato y pasarlo al formulario para así crear un nuevo grupo.**

Codigo del controlador grupo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Grupo;
use App\Models\Horario;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class GrupoController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class GrupoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $grupos = Grupo::paginate();

        return view('grupo.index', compact('grupos'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * $grupos->perPage());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $grupo = new Grupo();
/**Este es el código con cual funciona en la 2 imagen que mostré
( que me muestra solo el codigo_grupos)pero que no es funcional para el usuario**/
        $horario = Horario::pluck('codigo_horarios','id');
/**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/
        $horarios = Horario::all();
        return view('grupo.create', compact('grupo','horario'), array('horarios'=> $horarios));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate(Grupo::$rules);

        $grupo = Grupo::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('grupos.index')
            ->with('success', 'Grupo agregado con éxito..');
    }    

}
```

Vista de crear grupo

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('template_title')
    Create Grupo
@endsection

@section('content')
    <section class="content container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                @includeif('partials.errors')

                <div class="card card-default">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <span class="card-title">Crear Grupo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('grupos.store') }}"  role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf

                            @include('grupo.form')
                        </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       @include('grupo.modal.modalgrupohorario')
    </section>
@endsection
```

Vista del formulario

```
<div class="box box-info padding-1">
    <div class="box-body">

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('codigo_grupo') }}
            {{ Form::text('codigo_grupos', $grupo->codigo_grupos, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('codigo_grupos') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Codigo Grupo']) }}
            {!! $errors->first('codigo_grupos', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('cupo_grupo') }}
            {{ Form::text('cupo_grupos', $grupo->cupo_grupos, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('cupo_grupos') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Cupo Grupo']) }}
            {!! $errors->first('cupo_grupos', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
        </div>
<!-- Este es el código con cual funciona en la 2 imagen que mostré
( que me muestra solo el codigo_grupos)pero que no es funcional para el usuario -->
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('horario') }}
            {{ Form::select('horarios_id',$horario, $grupo->horarios_id, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('horarios_id') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => '--- Seleccione un Horario ---']) }}
            {!! $errors->first('horarios_id', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
        </div>
<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
        <!-- boton modal -->
        <br>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalGrupoHorario">Modal prueba horario</button>
        </div>
        <!-- boton modal -->
    <br>
    <div class="box-footer mt20">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="float-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('grupos.index') }}"> Volver</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Vista de la modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalGrupoHorario" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="ModalGrupoHorario" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalGrupoHorario">Horario</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                            <span id="card_title">
                                {{ __('Horario') }}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                <thead class="thead">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Codigo Horario</th>
                                        <th>Dia</th>
                                        <th>Hora Inicio</th>
                                        <th>Hora Final</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($horarios as $horario)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ $horario->codigo_horarios }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $horario->dia->nombre_dias }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $horario->horainicio->hora_inicios }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $horario->horafinale->hora_finales }}</td>
                                            <td>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Seleccionar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
```

Agradezco su atención, espero me puedan dar una luz para continuar.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente se hace creando un input tipo hidden y el valor se lo pones dinamicamente

En tu formulario pon el input(*No recomiendo laravel collective*)

```
<input id="horario_id" name="horario_id" type="hidden"></input>
```

Ya en tu javascript agregas un evento que al dar click en el horario de la modal le metes el valor del id al input que está oculto

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucionado!